# How exactly are scope variables in angularjs altered?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am quite new to AngularJS, I want a html file that can dynamically calculate the sum as when I update my variables (say a & b) using AngularJS.
Here is my code snippet

HTML:
[Code Snippet for HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORZyx.png)

Javascript: 
[Code Snippet for Javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUQDK.png)

On updating my input values, the sum still comes on to be 0, and does not get updated. Sorry for the mediocrity of the question, but pls suggest a solution.

Comment: Add the code in your questions instead of images please

Comment: The indentation is going haywire, if I add the code in the question. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: use Ctrl+M to insert code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a function to sum input value

Controller

```
$scope.a = 0; $scope.b = 0;
$scope.sum = function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Html

```
<input type="number" ng-model="a" />
<input type="number" ng-model="b" />
<div>
    {{sum(a,b)}}
</div>
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/11152/)

Comment: Works Perfectly, thank you. Although why does it now work, if i just do {{sum}}, is there any explanation?